# Help with simple logarithmic system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

It's simple, I just need a little bit of help to get started.
$$\log_yx-\log_xy=\frac{8}{3}$$
$$xy=16$$

Comment: the first leads to a quadratic equation, can be solved. then use the second equation to plug in x oy y,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide to get you started:

- write $\log_x y = \frac{1}{\log_y x}$ and then perhaps some quadratic formula might help to solve for $\log_x y$.

Comment: I get $\log_yx \in (3,-1/3)$ and $\log_xy \in (1/3,-3)$. How do I get to $x$ and $y$?

Comment: x and y must be positive.  Otherwise the logs are undefined.

Comment: @Hanlon If $\log_{y}(x)=3$ then $x=y^3$ and $xy = y^4=16 \implies ?$

Comment: Thanks. I think I can finish it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First just solve $1$. equation to get some more explicit connection between $x$ and $y$.

Change the base of logarithm to some neutral base and make some substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

With $u:=\dfrac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 y}, v:=\log_2 y$, we have the system

$$\begin{cases}u-\dfrac1u=\dfrac83,\\uv+v=4.\end{cases}$$

The first equation can be reduced to a quadratic one and solved for $u$, then the second gives $v$.

> $u=-\dfrac13,v=6$ or $u=3,v=1$.